How would I loop through a dictionary for specific fields in Ansible?
I created a dictionary of ansible packages filtered from ansible.package_facts, to only contain packages of a specific version. (example shown below)
"filtered_ansible_packages": {
    "cool_package1": [
       {
         "arch": "noarch",
         "epoch": "null",
         "name": "cool_package1",
         "release": "el7",
         "version": "1.2.6"
       }
    ],
    "cool_package2": [
       {
         "arch": "noarch",
         "epoch": "null",
         "name": "cool_package2",
         "release": "el7",
         "version": "1.4.7"
       }
    ]
 }

UPDATE: This is how filtered_ansible_packages is defined:

#another task
set_fact:
  filtered_ansible_packages: "{{ filtered_ansible_packages | default({}) | combine(new_item | items2dict) }}"
with_dict: "{{ ansible_facts.packages }}"
loop_control:
  label: "{{ item.key }}"
vars:
  el7_release: "{{ item.value | selectattr('release', 'search', 'el7') | list}}"
  new_item:
    - key: "{{ item.key }}"
      value: "{{ el7_releases}}"
when: el7_releases | list | length

What I want is to loop through each package and grab the name, release, version and arch.
Then I want to concatenate them into a single string variable we can call "full_package_name", where in the case of cool package 1 would be: "cool_package1.1.2.6.el7.noarch" then store those full package names into a list called "full_package_name_list".
What would be the best way to retrieve the data in the way that I need? should I transform it to a list with "dict2items"? I am new to Ansible so any help would be really appreciated.

As [tag:bash] is tagged, I assume that with "loop" and "variable" you're referring to features of a shell script. Try something like while read -r full_package_name; do …; done < <(jq -r '.filtered_ansible_packages[][] | [.name, .version, .release, .arch] | join(".")') using the JSON parser jq.

Bash cannot process JSON data natively, you need to use jq or a more general purpose scripting language with builtin JSON parsin capabilities.

Q: "Loop through each package and grab the name, release, version, and arch."
A: Convert the dictionary to a list and iterate subelements
    - debug:
        msg: |
          arch: {{ item.1.arch }}
          name: {{ item.1.name }}
          release: {{ item.1.release }}
          version: {{ item.1.version }}
      loop: "{{ filtered_ansible_packages | dict2items | subelements('value') }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.0.key }} {{ item.1.name }}"

gives
ok: [localhost] => (item=cool_package1 cool_package1) =>
  msg: |-
    arch: noarch
    name: cool_package1
    release: el7
    version: 1.2.6
ok: [localhost] => (item=cool_package2 cool_package2) => 
  msg: |-
    arch: noarch
    name: cool_package2
    release: el7
    version: 1.4.7


Q: "Store full package names into a list full_package_name_list"
A: Use json_query to select the attributes and join them
  full_package_name_list: "{{ filtered_ansible_packages |
                              json_query('*[].[name, version, release, arch]') |
                              map('join', '.') }}"

gives
  full_package_name_list:
  - cool_package1.1.2.6.el7.noarch
  - cool_package2.1.4.7.el7.noarch



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    filtered_ansible_packages:
      cool_package1:
        - {arch: noarch, epoch: 'null', name: cool_package1, release: el7, version: 1.2.6}
      cool_package2:
        - {arch: noarch, epoch: 'null', name: cool_package2, release: el7, version: 1.4.7}

    full_package_name_list: "{{ filtered_ansible_packages |
                                json_query('*[].[name, version, release, arch]') |
                                map('join', '.') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          arch: {{ item.1.arch }}
          name: {{ item.1.name }}
          release: {{ item.1.release }}
          version: {{ item.1.version }}
      loop: "{{ filtered_ansible_packages | dict2items | subelements('value') }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.0.key }} {{ item.1.name }}"

    - debug:
        var: full_package_name_list



What if the dictionary was defined differently? I updated the original question to show how I get the dictionary of "filtered_ansible_packages"

Q: "What I want is to loop through each package and grab the name, release, version and arch. Then I want to concatenate them into a single string variable we can call full_package_name ..."
A minimal example playbook
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - package_facts:

  - name: full_package_name_list
    debug:
      msg: "{{ full_package.name ~ '.' ~ full_package.version ~ '.' ~ full_package.release ~ '.' ~ full_package.arch }}"
    vars:
      full_package: "{{ item.value | first }}"
    with_dict: "{{ ansible_facts.packages }}"
    loop_control:
      label: "{{ item.key }}"

will provide such behavior.
One could even filter the package dictionary for certain properties like the release before.
